# Why is the line not changing?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsfiddle

I have a D3 chart which should update after 2 seconds. While the axis change, the line itself does not.

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/jwcngdLv/1/

I think this should be updating the axis and the line, but what am I missing?

```
// Make the changes
svg.select(".line")   // change the line
   .duration(1000).attr("d", valueline(data));
svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
   .duration(1000).call(xAxis);
svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
   .duration(1000).call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to add the class to the path like this:

```
svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
.classed("line", true) //add class to the path
.attr("d", valueline(data));
```

**Reason:**
In your update function you are using class name `line` to select the path.

```
 svg.select(".line")   // change the line
    .duration(1000).attr("d", valueline(data));
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zaukLfsL/)

Comment: Awesome. Can't say I understand why that is, but this is all new to me, so hopefully it'll come. Thanks!